# Reactive Extensions Updating UI

Tags: silverlight, system.reactive

I make this async webrequest call mutliple times(can be twice or thrice or even 6 times depending on conditions)

```
        var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

        var observableRequest = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(
            request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse);

        Observable.Timeout(observableRequest.Invoke(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)).
            Subscribe(response => { HandleListResult(response); },
            exception => { HandleListResultTimeOut(exception); });
```

I have a Collection (List)  in the ViewModel which has a Binding to a LisBox and i would like to keep adding to the collection after each response returns.

What is the best practice to make this happen using Reactive Extensions ? Would be great if someone can show me some sample code !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you'll be updating the UI via either a property that raises PropertyChanged or an ObservableCollection, it's best to use ObserveOnDispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate url flow directly into streams:

```
    public static IObservable<Stream> RequestToStream(
        this IObservable<string> source, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return
            from wc in source.Select(WebRequest.Create)
            from s in Observable
                .FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(wc.BeginGetResponse,
                    wc.EndGetResponse)()
                .Timeout(timeout, Observable.Empty<WebResponse>())
                .Catch(Observable.Empty<WebResponse>())
            select s.GetResponseStream();
    }
```

And then you need to observe your responces on UI, you need to use .ObserveOnDispatcher(), f.e.:

```
        Observable
            .Return("www.msdn.com")
            .RequestToStream(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(request => UpdateUI(Request));
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do i need to lock the List<string> object(which is bound to ListBox) before updating it ?Since the same handler will be called multiple times and i wonder what will happen when the second handler will try to update the List when the first handler is already updating it.

Thanks !

Comment: Can't happen. Each request to update the UI will happen on the same UI thread - so they will be serialized. No need to lock.

Comment: You could also use Defer and Retry to add more reliability to the call (i.e. if one of them times out, try again), but awesome use of Rx here!

Answer (score 2):

In [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net), this is done via CreateCollection()

```
IObservable<string> source; // Maybe this is a Subject<string> or whatever

myBoundCollection = source
    .SelectMany(webServiceCall) // This is your FromAsyncPattern func
    .CreateCollection();  // Pipe the Observable to a Collection
```

ReactiveUI handles all of the ObserveOn stuff to make sure it's synchronized and on the right threads, etc. This call returns immediately with an Empty list, then as results come in, the collection gets populated.